If i try to set src of an img variable that is not a valid url in ejs template, it throws an error
This is the code to fetch data from mongodb and then send it to ejs template to render.
the data object is fetched correctly, I checked by console.log the data object,and there are no validators set on the model.
the data returned from query ran mongoDB compass for said id:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "668b1dbc7360c5d0b660559a"
  },
  "title": "dsfgsgfsd",
  "price": 23,
  "description": "asdfasdf",
  "location": "fasfdasdfsadf",
  "image": "asddfadsf",
  "__v": 0
}

app.get('/campgrounds/:id',async (req, res) => {
   const { id } = req.params;
   const data = await Campground.findById(id);
   res.render("./campgrounds/campInfo", { data });
});

ejs template
<div class="row mb-3">
<div class="col-6">
<img src="<%= data.image %>" class="img w-100" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-6">
<p><%= data.description %></p>
</div>
</div>

it throws the following error:
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "asddfadsf" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Campground"
at SchemaObjectId.cast (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectId.js:250:11)
at SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1236:12)
at SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1653:17)
at cast (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:375:32)
at Query.cast (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4798:12)
at Query._castConditions (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2206:10)
at model.Query._findOne (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2526:8)
at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4342:80)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async file:///C:/Users/rajne/Desktop/CampGrounds/index.js:57:18 {
stringValue: '"asddfadsf"',
messageFormat: undefined,
kind: 'ObjectId',
value: 'asddfadsf',
path: '_id',
reason: BSONError: input must be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte Uint8Array, or an integer
at new ObjectId (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\bson\lib\bson.cjs:2362:23)
at castObjectId (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
at SchemaObjectId.cast (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectId.js:248:12)
at SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1236:12)
at SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1653:17)
at cast (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:375:32)
at Query.cast (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4798:12)
at Query._castConditions (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2206:10)
at model.Query._findOne (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2526:8)
at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\rajne\Desktop\CampGrounds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4342:80),
valueType: 'string'
}

Node.js v22.3.0

i tried almost everything i could.

So the current page is something like /campgrounds/668b1dbc7360c5d0b660559a and you're telling it to load the relative URL asddfadsf which resolves to /campgrounds/asddfadsf. So that is trying to pass asddfadsf as an ObjectId parameter to the same route handler which obviously isn't valid. In short, validate  the request parameters to avoid crashes like this
